# ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

Tags: oracle-xe

I downloaded a docker container with oraclexe 11g on Ubuntu 14.
Everything worked as expected, i created tables, insert data, etc and then i commit the container, generating a new image(same oracle image, but with my tables and data).

Problem:

I can´t connect to my database in my newly created image, either local or remote.
Any tips on that error?
Oracle image:
https://hub.docker.com/r/sath89/oracle-xe-11g/

```
**sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Fri May 6 20:13:43 2016
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact**



listener.ora
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
    )
  )
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = e68b846e86b8)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

tnsnames.ora
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = e68b846e86b8)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

lsnrctl status
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 06-MAY-2016 20:11:55
Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                06-MAY-2016 20:11:22
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 32 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/e68b846e86b8/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=e68b846e86b8)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

lsnrctl services
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 06-MAY-2016 20:12:34
Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the dockerfile mounting the oracle data folder
VOLUME "/u01/app/oracle"

When i commit my container, this folder is not saved into my new image, generating the errors to start the db.